# Permission Denied (Windows) - M2Devbox Installation Issue

Tags: magento2, windows, docker

I'm new to Magento, and to Docker for that matter...

Managed to get as far as executing the ./m2devbox-init.bat script which pulled the necessary files from the repo and did the installation but towards the end of the installation I got this error:

> **[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.**
>
> **[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin**
>
> **Executing shell command:**
>
> **mysql -h db -u root -proot -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS**
>
> **magento_integration_tests;"**
>
> **Executing shell command:**
>
> **cd /var/www/magento2 && php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer**
>
> **Enabled developer mode.**
>
> **Executing shell command:**
>
> **touch /home/magento2/state/enable_sync**
>
> **touch: cannot touch '/home/magento2/state/enable_sync': Permission denied**

If I was running Linux I would know my way around a little better but I'm a bit lost using Windows with Docker and Virtualbox.

Anyone can advise whereabouts I can find the location mentioned above to adjust the permission?

Also noticed that during installation, another terminal opens following the execution of the ./m2devbox-unison-sync.bat script and has the following error:

> **(./shared/webroot: No such file or directory)**
>
> **or to its parent ./shared**
>
> **(./shared: No such file or directory)**
>
> **Try 'timeout --help' for more information.**
>
> **Contacting server...**
>
> **Fatal error: Cannot find canonical name of ./shared/webroot: unable to cd either to it**

Not sure if the two issues above are in some way related.

Any help or direction appreciated. Have tried troubleshooting the issue without any success.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm also a beginner with Magento and Docker, but I think I've managed to make this devbox work.

My system: Windows 8.1 with Docker Toolbox

Let's start with the SECOND error:

Create a folder "shared/webroot" in the same folder where you have your "m2devbox-init.bat" file. 
In my case, I've set security permissions for "shared" and "webroot" folders by giving full control to group "Everyone", just to be sure.

Now, let's have a look at the FIRST error:

> touch /home/magento2/state/enable_sync
>
> touch: cannot touch '/home/magento2/state/enable_sync': Permission denied

How to fix:
 - find the id for your docker container that holds apache/php (run "docker ps", you should see 2 containers listed, one for the webserver and one for mysql)

- ssh into the docker container that holds apache/php (run "docker exec -it  bash")
- change permissions for */home/magento2/state* (run "chmod 0777 /home/magento2/state")
- exit from your docker container ssh session
- run again ./m2devbox-init.bat
- at this point, your Magento application should work as expected

After all this, I still had some issues with Unison not being able to sync all the files between host and guest. For that to work, I had to increase the value of a filesystem parameter (called max_user_watches). In order to do that:
 - ssh into the apache docker container (same as above)

- check the value stored in "/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches" (the 
  default is 8192, which seems to be to low for a Magento environment)
- increase that value by running the following command:

  echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
- exit from your docker container ssh session
- run (again) ./m2devbox-unison-sync.bat
- at this point, Unison should correctly watch any file changes

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am also facing same issue, i tried to execute echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p but it says read-only file system

Comment: @gulshanmaurya in order to fix that, mark that container as "priviledged" in docker-compose.yml

`services:
    web:
        container_name: magento2devbox_web_XXXXXX
        restart: always
        image: magento/magento2devbox-web:latest
        **privileged: true**`